# apache2 rewrite rule: delete any path from URL

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, mod-rewrite, rewrite, rewritecond

I'm going crazy with a Rewrite Rule on **Apache**.

Basically what I want to achieve is to rewrite any url like:

```
http[s]://www.example.com/something
```

to

```
https://www.example.com
```

I have a VHost on apache like the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias example
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example_courtesy
ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com

RedirectMatch 404 /\.git
RedirectMatch 404 /\.svn
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/html/example_courtesy>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
    DirectoryIndex index.php indice.htm
</Directory>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]


</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias example
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example_courtesy
ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com

RedirectMatch 404 /\.git
RedirectMatch 404 /\.svn
```

[...]

I tried deleting the [L] from the first rule and adding a rewrite rule like the following into *:443 VirtualHost:

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^80$
 RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME} [L,R]
```

What I receive is a rewrite loop, Firefox tells me "The page isn't redirecting properly".

I did many other tries with rewrite rules but no luck.

I only achieved to rewrite a specific URL like https://www.example.com/specific-path to https://www.example.com with a **RedirectMatch**, but this is not what I definitely want.

Any suggestions?

I searched here for a similar question but I didn't find a solution to my specific problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your RewriteCond for the *.443 section has an obvious issue with it.  HTTPS (typically) runs on port 443 (as the VirtualHost configuration shows) but your rewrite condition says 'If the server port is not 80, redirect to https://...'.

So, hit port 443, ask for content, get told to go to 443 because you're not on 80.  That's a loop.
`RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$` should work.

Personally, I would rather use `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on`.

Comment: It works if I use `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on` but only for HTTP requests. But if I want to redirect even the HTTP request how can I do? I would like to have any http or https request like http[s]://www.example.com/something redirected to https ://www.example.com/, I hope I was clear, thanks!

Comment: There was a typo, I would like to redirect HTTPS requests too. Maybe should I use mod_redirect instead of mod_rewrite?

Comment: Your problem is really a simple one if you follow it through logically.  You haven't yet defined (in your conf nor your question) what you don't want to be redirected from http to https. Define it in your head, then define it in your conf.  Apache is only going to do what you explicitly tell it to.